# How to convert SoapUI response to java object?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, soapui, unmarshalling

I want to convert the response(as `XML`) of `SoapUI` to `Java` class. For example this response :

```
<Response xmlns="http://localhost/activiti-rest/service/runtime/process-instances">
    <activityId>usertask1</activityId>
    <businessKey null="true"/>
    <id>2001</id>
    <processDefinitionId>ExampleProcess:1:1706</processDefinitionId>
    <processDefinitionUrl>http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions/ExampleProcess%3A1%3A1706</processDefinitionUrl>
    <suspended>false</suspended>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/process-instances/2001</url>
    <variables/>
</Response>
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Are you trying to _instanciate_ a class with the XML response or _create_ a new class at runtime? Just to clarify.

Comment: No,Should I do? Actually I can convert a class to XML and reverse,but in activiti-engine is there any class that can make this job I don't know. Thanks @AlexisLeclerc

Comment: You didn't answer my question. I was asking whether you want to simply _instanciate_ an object with a class you already have, or completely _create_ a new class at runtime. Notice the distinction between the two words in italics.

Comment: I'm trying _create_ a class at runtime.